# Takesaki theorem 1.8: Is functional well-defined?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, dual-spaces

Consider the following fragment from Takesaki's book "Theory of operator algebra I":
[image]

Why is $f_x$ well-defined? It seems to depend on the choice of decomposition $\omega = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n \omega_{\xi_n, \eta_n}$ (with $\{\alpha_n\}\in \ell^1$ and $\{\xi_n\}$ and $\{\eta_n\}$ orthonormal sequences). I think such a decomposition need not be unique in general.

Edit: $\mathscr{L}(\mathfrak{H})$ denotes bounded operators on the Hilbert space $\mathfrak{H}$ and $\mathscr{L}\mathscr{C}(\mathfrak{H})$ denotes compact operators on $\mathfrak{H}$.

Comment: Please describe the used notations.

Comment: @Berci Done. I don't quite now how to get the same fonts though.

Comment: @Berci: the question is tagged "operator-algebras" and it cites a major text in the area. Notation is standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no uniqueness in the sense you say, but that's not what's needed. If
$$
\omega = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n \omega_{\xi_n, \eta_n},\qquad \omega' = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n' \omega_{\xi_n', \eta_n'}
$$
and $\omega=\omega'$, this means that for any $x\in\mathscr C(\mathfrak H)$ you have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n \langle x\xi_n, \eta_n\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n' \langle x\xi_n', \eta_n'\rangle,
$$
which, as compacts are sot-dense in $\mathscr L(\mathfrak H)$, is exactly what you need.

Comment: Of course... Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I was a little confused by this point actually. Here, $\omega$ is a linear functional on compact operators, so it's not clear a priori why the first equality leads to the second. It would certainly be true for compact $x$, but I don't see it for bounded $x$.

Comment: @EuYu: the series $\sum_n|\alpha_n|$ converges (which is another way of saying that the dual of the compacts are the trace-class operators), which makes these functionals normal/sot-continuous. And the compacts are dense.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thanks for the response Martin. It seems to me (and please correct me if I'm wrong) that your argument requires knowing that these functionals are ultraweak/strong continuous. Alternatively it would suffice knowing that they're weak/strong-operator continuous on bounded subsets, together with something like Kaplansky's density theorem. But neither the ultraweak/strong topologies nor Kaplansky's have been introduced by Takesaki yet at this point in his book. I'm wondering if there's a way to show this in a self-contained manner.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I accepted too fast. The equality is only obvious for $x$ a compact operator (note the typo in your answer).

Comment: @EuYu I don't mind using weak/strong topology, but I did not think about this because Takesaki did not introduce it yet. I wrote an answer that uses this approach. Feedback is highly appreciated! :)

Comment: @Andromeda I think you missed a factor of M in the last term of your first inequality, but otherwise your argument looks perfect!

Comment: @EuYu Thanks! You are right, I corrected it.

Comment: @EuYu: I don't have Takesaki at hand right now. But what's the context, then? He says that every functional in the dual of the compacts is of the form $\sum_n\alpha_n\omega_{\xi_n,\eta_n}$. What's the condition on the $\{\alpha_n\}$, then?

Comment: @MartinArgerami The $\alpha_n$ are absolutely convergent as you say. Your argument is perfectly correct, I was just trying to find a proof that does not use concepts introduced later on in Takesaki. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @EuYu: The argument is what Andromeda wrote in her answer. It's what I mentioned in my earlier comment.

Comment: @EuYu: when I have the time, I'll check how the progression goes in Takesaki's book. The fact that every operator is a sot-limit of compacts (actually, finite-rank) does not require any machinery, though.

Answer (score 1):

**Claim**: $\omega = \sum_n \alpha_n \omega_{\xi_n, \eta_n}$, viewed as a functional on $\mathscr{L}(\mathfrak{H})$, is weakly continuous on bounded subsets.

**Proof**: Suppose that $x_\lambda \to 0$ in the weak topology and $M:= \sup_\lambda \|x_\lambda\|<\infty$. Then the estimate
\begin{align*}\left|\sum_n \alpha_n \omega_{\xi_n, \eta_n}(x_\lambda)\right| &\le \sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_n |\langle x_\lambda\xi_n, \eta_n\rangle| + M\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \alpha_n\end{align*}
together with the fact that $\sum_n \alpha_n < \infty$ ensures that $\omega(x_\lambda) \to 0$. This proves the claim. $\quad \square$

**Claim**: If $\omega = \sum_n \alpha_n \omega_{\xi_n, \eta_n}= \sum_n \alpha_n' \omega_{\xi_n', \eta_n'}$ as functionals on $\mathscr{L}\mathscr{C}(\mathfrak{H})$, then also as functionals on $\mathscr{L}(\mathfrak{H})$.

**Proof**: By the previous claim, it suffices to show that every element in $\mathscr{L}(\mathfrak{H})$ is a weak limit of a bounded net of elements in $\mathscr{LC}(\mathfrak{H})$. In fact, every such element is even a strong limit of such a bounded net because we can choose a net of finite-rank projections $\{p_\lambda\}$ such that $p_\lambda \to 1$ in the strong topology (such a net can be defined explicitly by considering an orthonormal basis for the Hilbert space) and then $xp_\lambda \to x$ strongly as well. $\quad \square$